# Can I use regex in find path?

Tags: linux, bash, regex, find

env = bash, centos7

My goal is to delete jenkins workspace cache files under specific path, except for today's.

Successful command :

```
cd /jenkins/jenkins/workspace/CMSvc_Build/caches/modules-2/files-2.1  
find . -mindepth 4 -type d -mtime +1 -print0 | sudo xargs -r0 rm -rf --
```

Then it deletes files as such :

```
./fruit.service.pysvc/apple-pysvc/4.3.8/4e5c29bc596b921fd955c43f284ce81e4949a55
./fruit.service.dtsvc/apple-dtsvc/4.3.8/f25fcc818b94ddb08f40664030e984ef829c2f9e
./fruit.service.dpsvc/apple-dpsvc/4.3.8/4f6424d46851660a9b6f35dcad4067566988151d
./fruit.service.bpsvc/apple-bpsvc/4.3.8/17ab02787bb70c0a72eb10bc1774b1cbd9f857a
./fruit.service.iasvc/apple-iasvc/4.3.8/9212eb6d964b3acfea3bb3ff4cb5525656fe66bd
./fruit.base.cm/apple-cm/4.3.8/eb55ff0355dd67c81065f44b92a953b21158a32b
./fruit.base.st/apple-st/4.3.8/7e4f58eed582252135e9bba266a15bcf61047
./fruit.base.dc/apple-dc/4.3.8/e2b5de519f21ec179e990304b83f3f066dab6f58
./fruit.base.pd/apple-pd/4.3.8/91a51c2f3ca33d24b646472888b33194e2a70e18
./fruit.service.acsvc/apple-acsvc/4.3.8/f543a1f4ce56697e7375b35a59003efd91b08bb2
./fruit.base.ac/apple-ac/4.3.8/cbc3dd6eeecca073aabe290effdcf8e21015eb2e
./fruit.base.at/apple-at/4.3.8/f33fbce61a9542cd51e152b4dec75671e624dec6
./fruit.service.arsvc/apple-arsvc/4.3.8/64eda8f3672916c86c0b2683eaf75f54468eda5e
./fruit.service.lnsvc/apple-lnsvc/4.3.8/ead15c00ce72c4ea3ddd061a5b482cd6ca2f54d0
./fruit.service.sfsvc/apple-sfsvc/4.3.8/d69715f8a87d8411e1e595fd13de039ccf6f5d98
./fruit.base.xp/apple-xp/4.3.8/dcb11249b7202e93d096748f58204ac4b864203
./fruit.base.ar/apple-ar/4.3.8/9010673f7b6def7ffeb0f8ffdaa526e34c56f38b
./fruit.base.sv/apple-sv/4.3.8/3d0d02472e454ad3e3f1ba1a76e7c1386787fcc3
```

My problem is I have so many other directories than `CMSvc_Build`, that I want to use the command from `/jenkins/jenkins/workspace/`.

I tried using `find . -mindepth 8 -regex ".*/.*/caches/.*/.*/.*"`, but it went deeper than my target directories.

Jenkins temp directories seems to have 39~40 random characters.

How do I solve this?

Comment: You should be really careful if you really want to programmatically delete folders on your system based on a regular expression.

Comment: "but it went deeper" – It's hard to test this without knowing the whole exact directory structure and all your requirements, but *maybe* all you need is `-maxdepth` and/or `[^/]*` instead of `.*` in the right places of the regex. Note each `.*` in your original regex *may* match a substring containing one or more `/`. Do tests on expendable directory trees.